# T-SQL 'IF' condition can not recognize column name

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to execute this query with some 'conditional logic', it is my first attempt doing something like this in databases.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @iddevice INT;
SET @iddevice = 15;
IF(@iddevice = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortA')
 BEGIN
  UPDATE DEVICEATTRIBUTES
  SET VALUE = '4701'
  WHERE IDDEVICE = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortA'
 END


IF(@iddevice = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortB')
 BEGIN
  UPDATE DEVICEATTRIBUTES
  SET VALUE = '4711'
  WHERE IDDEVICE = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortB'
 END


IF(@iddevice = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'IP')
 BEGIN
  UPDATE DEVICEATTRIBUTES
  SET VALUE = '172.19.106.201'
  WHERE IDDEVICE = 15 AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'IP'
 END;

GO
```

I am aware that something with the syntax is wrong, my question is ... how can I add `DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE` inside the 'if' clause?

Comment: Maybe you must have an input variable about deviceattribute to value in the if. But if you want to check the value of field is not a right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script you can re-write as follow:

```
DECLARE @iddevice INT;
SET @iddevice = 15;

UPDATE DEVICEATTRIBUTES
SET VALUE = 
CASE
    WHEN DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortA' THEN '4701'
    WHEN DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'PortB' THEN '4711'
    WHEN DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = 'IP' THEN '172.19.106.201'
END
WHERE IDDEVICE = @iddevice AND DEVICEATTRIBUTES.DEVICEATTRIBUTE IN ('PortA', 'PortB', 'IP')
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE DA
    SET VALUE = '4701'
    FROM DEVICEATTRIBUTES DA JOIN
         (VALUES ('PortA', '4701'),
                 ('PortB', '4711'),
                 ('IP', '172.19.106.201')
         ) V(DEVICEATTRIBUTE, VALUE)
         ON DA.DEVICEATTRIBUTE = V.DEVICEATTRIBUTE
    WHERE IDDEVICE = 15;
```

The `VALUES` clause is a handy way to add in the values you want to change -- and it reduces the risk of typos.

However, in your code, you can just use three `UPDATE`s.  The `IF` statements are not necessary.  If no rows match the `WHERE` clause then no rows are updated.